# how to set gaps between lines

Tags: html

I need to set space for each line `<br>` tag is taking huge.

```
<font color="white">
ani <br> </br>
hna <br> </br>
Raj <br> </br>
Parya <br> </br>
Sith  <br> </br>
Sududa <br> </br>
</font>
```

Comment: Looks like you ned to get your hands dirty with some CSS. Remove the <font> tag, it's a bit old hat to be using that. See my answer about placing text inside a `<p>` then styling that the way you want including the use of `line-height`

Comment: Just a sidenote: The `<br>` tag is not meant to be closed in that way. Try closing it by either using the XML-style `<br />` or by simply NOT closing it at all. Both are supported.

Also - try to avoid `<font>` and move on to CSS instead. There are very good tutorials on [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QFHPh/

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    p {
       line-height: 1.5em;        
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        this is <br />
        a test<br />
        of good text spacing
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to set the p in css and call in my html

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a full HTML document. The CSS will affect all `<p>` tags in your document. If you wanted to only affect certain <p> tags then you will have to add a `class` attribute as shown on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CL4s/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `<p>` tags for each line instead of double `<br>`s? Or use an `<ul>`? You'll have more control over the layout.

But if you must use `<br>` use [`line-height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height) and only one `<br>` for each line.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are trying to close each `<br>` tag, this isn't possible and instead you are creating two line breaks. Remove one of these and you'll get normal line breaks:
http://jsfiddle.net/LMXNY/

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre style="color:white">
ani 
hna 
Raj 
Parya 
Sith 
Sududa
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `line-height` property in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

By golly, if it looks like a list and acts like a list, it may in fact be a list! Change the bottom margin for the list item to change the spacing between items.

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul {
    color: white;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
</style>
<ul>
  <li>ani</li> 
  <li>hna</li> 
  <li>Raj</li> 
  <li>Parya</li> 
  <li>Sith</li> 
  <li>Sududa</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing,
you don't use

```
<br> </br>
```

It is only:

```
<br />
```

Then on your problem, use the following

```
<p style="line-height: 20px;">ani
</p><p style="line-height: 20px;">hna
</p><p style="line-height: 20px;">Raj 
</p><p style="line-height: 20px;">Parya 
</p><p style="line-height: 20px;">Sith
</p><p style="line-height: 20px;">Sududa
</p>
```

Increase/decrease the number in line-height ('20'px), to increase/decrease the space between the lines respectively.